# Julia set is plotted mirrored at y-axis

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am trying to plot the Julia Set for the function f(z)=z^2+c (see code below). My Julia set for c=-.1+0.7i looks as in the attached picture.[My Julia set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciKd0.png).

If i compare this to the pictures of the Julia set in Wikipedia for c~-0.1+0.7i it is mirrored at the y-axis. Its clear for me that I could get the picture I want by just exchange  c=complex(-0.1,0.7) with c=complex(-0.1,-0.7) to get the correct plot. But why is it drawing it the wrong way, I do not understand it.

```
def mandelbrot_binary(Re,Im, max_iterations):
    z=complex(Re,Im)
    #z=0.0j
    c=complex(-0.1,0.7)
    for i in range(max_iterations):
        z=z*z+c
        if np.sqrt(z.real*z.real+z.imag*z.imag) > 2 and np.sqrt(z.real*z.real+z.imag*z.imag) >= np.sqrt(c.real*c.real+c.imag*c.imag):
            return 1


columns=2000
rows=2000

result=np.zeros([rows,columns])

#np.linspace(start,stop,numbers): Return evenly spaced numbers over a specified interval.
for row_index, Re in enumerate(np.linspace(-2,2,num=rows)):
    for column_index, Im in enumerate(np.linspace(-1.5,1.5,num=columns)):
        result[row_index,column_index]=mandelbrot_binary(Re,Im,100)
        
plt.figure(dpi=2000)
#interpolation method used
plt.imshow(result.T, extent=[-2,1,-1,1])
plt.xlabel('Re(z)')
plt.ylabel('Im(z)')
plt.show
```

Comment: This looks more like a programming/Python problem than a mathematical problem to me. Perhaps you have to set the "origin" parameter to "lower"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *result* is a matrix. The indices of a matrix increase from top to bottom. This is top and bottom that are reversed in your picture.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I see the problem. Do you have also a suggestion how to solve the issue with using a matrix?

Comment: You need to iterate backward on the y-axis when you are filling the matrix.